# How to publish and deploy multi-channel bots without azure?

Tags: c#, botframework

once I read about Microsoft bot framework, I realized that it is a platform to code once and run everywhere... I mean, you code once and then you have bots for Telegram, Facebook, slack, skype and so on.
Is my understanding about Microsoft bot framework correct? Or I'm expecting too much of it?

Then I downloaded Bot Composer for my windows laptop and created a bot.
It works on emulator.

#### My problem/Question is how to publish and deploy my bot without azure?

I have a VPS on Hetzner, and I want to host my Bots in that vps.
The bot composer has only options working with azure, I don't have Microsoft app ID and Microsoft app password. What should I do ?

[image]

In [this chart](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk), It can be seen that some social platforms work with azure, and some others work with sdk, for example Telegram -->> SDK , What does it mean ?!?!?

Does it mean that you have to pay for Azure to publish your bot for Telegram ?

In [this link](https://dev.botframework.com/bots/new), I have to register a bot, there is a button there which says : Create Microsoft App ID and password.

I clicked on it and created one, there is Microsoft App ID in it, but there is no password.
[image]

I know I wrote too much :)) but I got very confused because I think the documentation is very unclear and the boundary between paid services and unpaid services is not clear...

Can anyone tell an instruction of how to deploy an simple echo bot on a VPS for multiple platforms without azure ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a bunch of questions , will try to synthetize.

1. Yes it's a code once, use from several channels... but not all channels have the same capabilities.
2. A bot application is "just" a state machine with a REST API endpoint to receive messages and send the replies back (seen from 30,000 ft )
3. You can host your app anywhere, it just has to have a valid public https address that you can configure in the Bot Channel Registration in Azure.
4. Azure Bot Service is a channel aggregator, that handles all the connection details for the channels listed as "Azure" in the chart you mentioned. Those channels are handled "automagically" by the bot framework.

   You might want to read a blog post I wrote some time ago, it's a bit dated but still conceptually valid: 
   [How does a Bot Builder v4 bot work?](https://www.coderepo.blog/posts/how-does-a-bot-builder-v4-bot-work/)
5. For those channels not in Azure, you have to handle each channel with a provider-supplied SDK in your web app. Of course, you could also implement authorization and all the details by yourself, after all it's just an API endpoint.
6. You don't really have to pay Azure for using the bot service channels, if you use the [standard channels](https://azure.microsoft.com/pricing/details/bot-services/), and premium channels are low cost.
7. As for deploying outside Azure, supposing you'll still use the free or close-to-free Bot Service:

   - Follow section 1-3 in [Deploy your bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-deploy-az-cli?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp)
   - Deploy the web app wherever you want (even locally using [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) similar to what I show in [another blog post](https://www.coderepo.blog/posts/how-to-receive-events-bot-framework-sdk-v4-web-api-bot/#deployment).
   - With all of the above in place, you should be able to test the bot from the channel webchat or even from Telegram, once you enable it, while your app is running in VS

Comment: Thank you for your time  put on writing this answer. This and your blog post were very helpful. I wonder I could do it without registration... but it seems that's not possible.

Comment: Glad to help , You could do without registration, but then you wouldn't use Bot Framework SDK and, for example, you'd have to explore, say Telegram's API and connect to their servers to implement the communication or find a suitable SDK. But that's a lot of work and, depending on what you're looking for, it might not pay back.