# What's the difference between app and bot channel?

Tags: azure, botframework

Creating a chat bot in Azure is confusing because there are so many different components which have to be created.  I'm trying to understand all these parts, specifically:

**App Registration**:  This is created with a command like `az ad app create`.  This does not appear in the Azure portal under *All Resources* (??).  Instead it appears under App Registrations.  This has an *Application (client) ID* in the portal.

**Bot Channels Registration**:  This has a different *Microsoft App ID* and password in the portal.

What's the difference between these two things, and which ID and password do I use in my code?

P.S. In addition to these two resources, I also have an app service and app service plan.  These parts I think I understand.

Comment: Hi, I answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67273652/how-to-publish-and-deploy-multi-channel-bots-without-azure) a few days ago, it might help you with your doubts.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to publish and deploy multi-channel bots without azure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67273652/how-to-publish-and-deploy-multi-channel-bots-without-azure)

Answer (score 2):

**Azure App registrations:** This will help to configure authentication and authorization workflows for a variety of different client types. So the unique "Client ID" and "Tenant ID" we will use for the authentication and authorization in the azure ad.

**Bot Channel Registration:** A bot channel registration with Azure, uses channels to facilitate communication with users. That's means a channel is a connection between communication applications and a bot. It will act as a secure bridge communication.

**Reference:**

1. [Bot Channel Registration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-quickstart-registration?view=azure-bot-service-4.0)

Answer (score 0):

The App Registration in Azure AD serves as your bot's identity and authorization for accessing Azure resources, whereas the Bot Channels Registration enables your bot to communicate with users on specific messaging channels.

In your bot's code, you'll use the Application (client) ID from the App Registration to authenticate with Azure AD.

Whereas whenever you want to use messaging channels like WhatsApp, Teams or Skype, you will use the Microsoft App ID and password from the Bot Channels Registration for authentication.